# NetLogo: calculate distance to other turtles and make them dissatisfied if another turtle is too close

Tags: netlogo

I sprouted my turtles over the patches and in the 'go' I want each turtle to calculate if another turtle is too close (based on a certain threshold of X  meters/patches). If another turtle is too close, i want the turtle to become 'dissatisfied'.
Movements of the turtles are not required.

What is the best way to do this? The only piece of code for the go procedure I have so far is as follows:

```
to go
  ask n-of initial-number-tourists (patches with [ lagoon_proximity = 1])
  [
    sprout 1 [
      set color black
      set size 10
    ]
  ]
tick 
end
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating more turtles and doesn't have anything about checking distances so it is not clear how it is related to the problem you are trying to solve. However, the following code measure the distance to the nearest turtle and prints a message if that is less than 5.

```
ask turtles
[ let nearest min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
  if distance nearest < 5 [ show "I feel crowded" ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Indeed, the code I have so far is not related to checking distances yet. The intention is to sprout turtles each tick based on the amount of satisfied/dissatisfied turtles from the previous tick. So, if in the first tick 500 turtles are sprouted, and 400 of them are identified as satisfied, then these 400 will be sprouted in the next tick.

Comment: StackOverflow is to help you fix your code, you need to actually try and do it yourself (and describe what is wrong with the code) so there is something to fix